# Is there a way to convert this into a "while loop" or a "do while loop"?

Tags: java

I am trying to convert this code into a while loop or a do while loop.  I don't quite grasp the best understanding of the subject.  Can anyone help?

This is the project I am trying to create a loop for.  I'm not sure what the loop would be used for:

The Barking Lot is a dog boarding facility. It provides boarding for any number of days and
additional services such as grooming and walking. The Barking Lot currently has three
employees, a list of 40 dog clients, and room to board eight dogs at any one time. One required
program must be able to estimate profits for a day. The facility can board eight dogs at a time; it
charges $25 a day for dogs that weigh more than 50 pounds and $20 a day for smaller dogs. The
facility’s expenses include $2 per day per dog for food (no matter the size of the dog), and $30
per day for utilities. Develop the logic for a program, and implement the program that allows a
user to enter the number of large dogs boarded; assume that the rest are small dogs and that the
facility is full. Output is the total revenue collected for the day, total expenses, and the
difference. Allow the user to request an unlimited number of profit estimates at a time

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bark {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 25;
    int Small = 0;
    int Large = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
    Small = Scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
    Large = Scanner.nextInt();

    int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
    int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
    int Facility = 30;
    int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
    int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);

    if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
      System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
      System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
      System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));

    } else
      System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you used a loop in different code before? What about it confuses you?

Comment: Why brute force it? I suggest you read about the [Simplex algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) and [Linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). Oh, and `for (int small = 8; small >= 0; small--) { for (int large = 0; large < 8 - small; large++) { /* calc here */ } }`

Comment: Well, it is for a project I am trying to complete.  I am confused on how exactly it would be converted.  i wish I could keep it the way it is.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)? What block of code do you want to execute `while` a condition is true?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing the concept of loops in general. When you use a loop in programming, you use it to repeat something over and over again. What are you trying to repeat?

Comment: I'm not quite sure.  Let me post my project.

Comment: I just added my project to the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what part of your code you would like to loop (I mean the result you want to achieve). So I will leave a coding style recommendation, that might help you in the near future! ;-)

```
    // Comment your code. You are going to need it and avoid some people
    // swearing at your code. :-)

    // Always use first letter lowercase and other words in upper when
    // programming in Java (variables, methods). Upper for classes.
    int variableName = 0;
    public class Bark { ... }
    int final MY_CONSTANT = 0;
    public void myMethod() { ... }

    // Not good to use variables like "x". You will easily loose track of
    // what they mean.
    int valueOfSomething = 20;
```

If what you want is reprocessing (like run the code again after it is done), here's what you could do.

```
    public class Bark {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           // Declare variables
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int valueSmall = 20;
           int valueLarge = 25;
           int small = 0;
           int large = 0;
           int quit = 0;

           while (quit == 0) {
               // Ask for user input
               System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
               small = scanner.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
               large = scanner.nextInt();

               // Perform accountability
               int revenue = ((small * valueSmall) + (large * valueLarge));
               int food = ((small + large) * (2));
               int facility = 30;
               int expenses = (food + facility);
               int difference = (revenue - expenses);

               if ((small + large) <= 8) {
                   System.out.println("Revenue is " + revenue);
                   System.out.println("Expenses = " + expenses);
                   System.out.println("Difference = " + difference);

               } else {
                   System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
               }

               // Ask if user wants to quit (No input validation!)
               System.out.println("Quit? Enter 0 for NO or 1 for YES:");
               quit = scanner.nextInt();
           }

           System.out.println("Goodbye");
        }
    }
```

Another way to accumulate the number of Dogs until it reaches the limit.

```
    public class Bark {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           // Declare variables
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           int valueSmall = 20;
           int valueLarge = 25;
           int small = 0;
           int large = 0;

           while (small + large <= 8) {
               // Ask for user input, notice I am accumulating using +=
               System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
               small += scanner.nextInt();
               System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
               large += scanner.nextInt();

               // Perform accountability
               int revenue = ((small * valueSmall) + (large * valueLarge));
               int food = ((small + large) * (2));
               int facility = 30;
               int expenses = (food + facility);
               int difference = (revenue - expenses);

               // Print the report
               System.out.println("Revenue is " + revenue);
               System.out.println("Expenses = " + expenses);
               System.out.println("Difference = " + difference);
           }

           // If number exceeds the limit, your loop breaks and you print the message.
           System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
           System.out.println("Goodbye");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If what you want is to accumulate the number of small and large dogs (like the capacity) while you loop, you are going to need an accumulator (the fancy name for a variable that accumulates things). If you get the inputs and assign to the variables "small" and "large" every time, it will have a unique entered value in every iteration of the loop. So instead of saying small = scanner.nextInt(); you can say small += scanner.nextInt;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to quit once small + large > 8, so that should be your loop condition:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bark {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 20;
        int y = 25;
        int Small = 0;
        int Large = 0;

        while (Small + Large <= 8) {
            System.out.println("Enter number of small dogs: ");
            Small = Scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
            Large = Scanner.nextInt();

            int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
            int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
            int Facility = 30;
            int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
            int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);
            if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
                System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
                System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
                System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));
            }
        }

    System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
    }
}
```

Here is a test result:

```
> javac Bark.java

> java Bark
Enter number of small dogs:
1
Enter number of large dogs:
2
Revenue is 70
Expenses = 36
Difference = 34
Enter number of small dogs:
4
Enter number of large dogs:
4
Revenue is 180
Expenses = 46
Difference = 134
Enter number of small dogs:
4
Enter number of large dogs:
5
The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.
```

Comment: I am getting an error message saying that reached the end of file while parsing. I can't find where.

Comment: @Joshua Add a } at the end.

Comment: @aksh1t it didn't work.

Comment: @JoshuaTimms, it was the missing `}` that broke the code. I apologize for that. I was tying up the answer on my phone and I didn't see that I had done it because I forgot to tab over when I started writing the main method on my phone. I included a test result output to show that it works when the while loop condition breaks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the only place you'd really use a loop is either as stated above, when theres no more room to board dogs, OR because the question says "Allow the user to request an unlimited number of profit estimates at a time".
And for that one, you'd just assign a variable that closes your program.  However using a do-while loop in that circumstance may be better if you want the program to ALWAYS run at least ONCE. For the previous guys answer, the while loop will suffice because you don't want to run it if you already have 40 dogs in boarding for example.

***:::::EDIT:::::***
Reading over your question, its clear you missed a few things in your original answer. 
FIRST OFF near the end it says ONLY enter large dogs, so *SmallDogsBoarded = 8 - numberOfLargeDogsBoarded* (however i'd probably make 8 a variable, incase the company gets room for more then 8 dogs in the future), so declare a variable '*maxBoardedDogs = 8*' therefore 
***smallDogsBoarded = maxBoardedDogs - numberOfLargeDogsBoarded***

Moving onto the actual question, if you wanted to make it a loop, I'd do something like

```
do{
  print line to user 'enter number of large dogs boarded or '-1' to quit'
  get numberOfLargeDogsBoarded

  */* say they enter something like a '-1' for quit, or a 47, in this case numberOfLargeDogsBoarded --MUST-- be somewhere between 0 and maxBoardedDogs (0-8 here) */*
  if(numberofLargeDogsBoarded is valid){
     calculate smallDogsBoarded(*explained above*)
     calculate profits using a formula
else 
     prompt user to re-enter the numberOfLargeDogsBoarded as it wasnt -1 and it WASNT between 0-8
     get user answer, calculate the profits.
}(while numberOfLargeDogsBoarded not equal to -1[our escape sequence])
```

Comment: So by unlimited number of profit estimates at a time you are saying I hsould have it so that it runs again every time it calculates the outcomes?

Comment: Leesgsma is that what you meant?

Comment: @JoshuaTimms check above, its just psuedocode but its easy to understand and convert your current program to that.